# Sharing an AWS Cognito / Amplify Auth Configuration between two projects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have AWS Amplify within a project that uses Auth only.  I want to transfer the Auth configuration settings to a new project.  Can we just copy `aws-exports` to the new project or do we need to do anything else?

Basically the goal is to share the same user pool between two different projects such that both projects authenticate against the same user pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work by just copy-pasting the project files. However, it's a good idea to create a new app client and configure it for the new project. Later if you want to track requests from these applications separately, this is necessary. While hosting you might need 2 different hostings for these two projects. Then also this will come handy for you.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, the Amplify docs now have an example of how to go about doing this [see here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/teams/multi-frontend#workflow).

I have a similar need -- sharing auth across different applications.